# How can I adjust the water level in a Grohe inner wall toilet?

Tags: water, toilet, level

How do I adjust the water level in the toilet bowl itself? With flushing there is a gush of water that actually flies forward and onto the floor, not really ideal. I think it's because the level of water inside the bowl is too low but I have no idea how to adjust this...a more traditional toilet, no problem, but this one it too high tech for me!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the inside of the toilet? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: The bowl level is dictated by the trap height (u bend) if there is not proper venting it may get sucked down lower, on standard toilets during the tank refill a small amount is added to the bowl. Is yours a tanked model or pressure vessel type.

Comment: It has a blue plastic tank behind the wall, this much I know...but now that it's built-in, I'm guessing there is no way to adjust the trap height as you have mentioned :(

Answer (score 1):

The geometry of the toilet bowl itself determines the water level, so it’s not adjustable. Try adding water with a bucket and you will see the surface area return to where it was designed to be. The flush action is designed to get as much force out of the six liters of water as possible, so there will be turbulence. I recommend closing the lid before flushing. With European toilets, it seems to be a matter of us adapting to them.

Comment: Thank you, it's too bad this is the way, I should have researched this type of toilet more but it looks so much better with the bulk of it hidden behind ceramic tile...having drops come flying out even with the lid closed is not so pleasant!

Comment: @Ian Sorry to hear. Is this a dual flush toilet? If so, does the water splash out when the smaller volume button is pressed?

Comment: Hello there, it is a dual flush and with your question in mind, I went and flushed with the larger button and it did not splash! Coincidental perhaps, but for now I'll tell my kids to only use the BIG button :)  Not good for water conservation but better to avoid cleaning the floor...thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Ian That makes me think something is amiss with the mechanism. You can take off the plate covering the actuator and peer down into the tank. Does anything look out of place?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I called Grohe support, and they gave me a flow reductor free of charge. It doesn't completely OK, but kind of a solution. If you search for 'Grohe 42300000' online, you'll find the piece.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.